# Primefaces DatePicker does not update its position on window rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

We use a [DatePicker](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/datepicker?id=datepicker) component in our project. Primefes Version 8.0.

The position of the DatePicker popup does not change after the position of the input field has changed (for example, after rotating the tablet). The problem was [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803154/primefaces-calendar-does-not-readjust-its-position-on-window-rotation) for the [Сalendar](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/calendar) component, but we use DatePicker because:

> DatePicker is designed to replace the old p:calendar component.

You can see this problem on the [official website](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datepicker/datePicker.xhtml).

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

After changing the screen size, the pop-up position was not updated:
[image: After changing the screen size, the pop-up position was not updated]

Is there any way to fix this by extending `PrimeFaces.widget.Calendar` with javascript?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this right now for yourself just add this Javascript to your page or site.

**Example XHTML:**

```xml
<p:datePicker id="popup" widgetVar="dpPopup" value="#{calendarView.date2}" />
```

**JavaScript to add to your page:**

```js
$(window).on('resize.datepicker', function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (item in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
            widget = PrimeFaces.widgets[item];
            if (widget instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.DatePicker) {
                    widget.jq.datePicker('alignPanel');
            }
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

Issue reported: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5984

Fixed for 9.0: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/5985

Comment: thank you, it works! Is it possible to extend the component so that I don't have to add this fix for each element?

Comment: Edited my answer above to be generic and find any DatePicker not a specific DatePicker.